# Serious printing out of XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="university_students.css" ?>
<university>
    <students>
        <student sid="sckl9999">
            <name>Schmitt</name>
            <firstname>Klaus</firstname>
            <courses>
                <course cid="IM120">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="WS13" type="simple">4.7</grade>
                        <grade attempt="2" term="SS14" type="simple">5.0</grade>
                            <grade attempt="3" term="WS14" type="simple">1.3</grade>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM130">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="complex">2.1</grade>
                        <course cid="IM131">
                            <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">2.2</grade>
                        </course>
                        <course cid="IM132">
                            <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="simple">2.3</grade>
                        </course>
                        <course cid="IM133">
                            <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">2.0</grade>
                        </course>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM140">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">1.7</grade>
                </course>
            </courses>
        </student>
        <student sid="sckl9999">
            <name>Putin</name>
            <firstname>Wladimir</firstname>
            <courses>
                <course cid="IM120">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">1.7</grade>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM130">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="complex">2.3</grade>
                    <course cid="IM131">
                        <grade attempt="2" term="WS14" type="simple">2.3</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="IM132">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="simple">2.7</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="IM133">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">2.7</grade>
                    </course>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM140">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">1.7</grade>
                </course>
            </courses>
        </student>
        <student sid="sckl9999">
            <name>Merkel</name>
            <firstname>Angela</firstname>
            <courses>
                <course cid="IM120">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="simple">1.0</grade>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM130">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="complex">1.1</grade>
                    <course cid="IM131">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">1.3</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="IM132">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="SS14" type="simple">2.3</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="IM133">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">1.3</grade>
                    </course>
                </course>
                <course cid="IM140">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="WS14" type="simple">2.0</grade>
                </course>
            </courses>
        </student>
    </students>
</university>
```

And the follwoing XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Following errors were found:</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="grade[@type='simple']">
            <xsl:if test="not(.='1.0' or .='1.3' or .='1.7' or .='2.0' or .='2.3' or .='2.7' or .='3.0' or .='3.3' or .='3.7' or .='4.0' or .='4.3' or .='4.7' or .='5.0')">
                <h3>
                    Simple grade <xsl:value-of select="."/> not correct in course <xsl:value-of select="../@cid" /> under term <xsl:value-of select="@term" /> at attempt <xsl:value-of select="@attempt" />.
                </h3>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT should check for any grade in the XML file until it has the type "simple" and then it should check the value if it fits to the if statement. My problem is, that I get the following output:

```
Following errors were found:
Schmitt Klaus 2.1
Simple grade 2.2 not correct in course IM131 under term WS14 at attempt 1.
Putin Wladimir 2.3 Merkel Angela 1.1
```

The third line is what I need, but why is there another second and fourth line I don't really need? Did I make a mistake and can you correct it plase?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be concerned about writing "serious" XSLT, you should also

- always output literal text content inside `xsl:text` in order to always be in control of which characters are written to the output tree
- perhaps put all allowed grade values in a variable and store them as a sequence
- as suggested by leu already, add the empty template matching `text()` to override the built-in template
- explicitly state the output method `html` and also use `strip-space` to get rid of all whitespace-only text nodes

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Following errors were found:</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="grade[@type='simple']">

            <xsl:variable name="allowed-grades" select="('1.0','1.3','1.7','2.0','2.3','2.7','3.0','3.3','3.7','4.0','4.3','4.7','5.0')"/>

            <xsl:if test="not(string(.) = $allowed-grades)">
                <h3>
                    <xsl:text>Simple grade </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text> not correct in course </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@cid" />
                    <xsl:text> under term </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@term" />
                    <xsl:text> at attempt </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@attempt" />
                    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                </h3>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Following errors were found:</h2>
      <h3>Simple grade 2.2 not correct in course IM131 under term WS14 at attempt 1.</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Unrelated, but "Following errors were found:" is not a grammatical English sentence in my opinion. You'd have to use "*The* following errors were found:".

Answer (score 1):

The built-in templates print out text-nodes of the input XML. Since your XSL has no explicit rule for text-nodes, they are printed.

Knowing this, we can easily avoid those strings you don't want. Just add this template

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```